# The python code to upload a .txt file to be read on the command prompt

Tags: python, upload, command, output, prompt

im supposed to have a code where when the user opens the command prompt they are asked to upload a .txt file to read for selling mistakes and give the user the data.
What i need is how do i put a upload function

Comment: upload where? show some code

Comment: How do they upload? Drag and drop, type in a path, paste the content?